# Rails migration - change column type from float to jsonb in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonb, rails-migrations

I am trying to convert column type from float to jsonb in rails. but it is giving this error.

```
 Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR:  cannot cast type double precision to json
LINE 1: ...es" ALTER COLUMN "quote_amounts" TYPE jsonb USING CAST(quote...
                                                             ^
: ALTER TABLE "vendor_quotes" ALTER COLUMN "quote_amounts" TYPE jsonb USING CAST(quote_amounts AS jsonb)
```

I have used this migration to change the column type

```
def change
    change_column :vendor_quotes, :quote_amounts, 'jsonb USING CAST(quote_amounts AS jsonb)'
  end
```

I have tried other syntax but still ends up with the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default cast from `double precision` to `jsonb` (as you've found). However, there is a [`to_jsonb` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE):

> `to_jsonb(anyelement)`
> Returns the value as `json` or `jsonb`. Arrays and composites are converted (recursively) to arrays and objects; otherwise, if there is a cast from the type to `json`, the cast function will be used to perform the conversion; otherwise, a scalar value is produced. For any scalar type other than a number, a Boolean, or a null value, the text representation will be used, in such a fashion that it is a valid `json` or `jsonb` value.

So you should be able to say:

```
change_column :vendor_quotes, :quote_amounts, 'jsonb using to_jsonb(quote_amounts)'
```

or

```
change_column :vendor_quotes, :quote_amounts, :jsonb, using: 'to_jsonb(quote_amounts)'
```